# Sharepoint 2007 - Date diference

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007, calculated-column, date-time

i need to determine the number of days between two calendar dates. I have create a 2 columns, the first Date 1 and the second Date 2. The date is chosen by clicking on the calendar.

What i require is a third column call Date 3, that calculates in number of days the difference between Date 2 and Date 1 `(Date3 = Date2 - Date1)`.

The version of my SharePoint is 2007...please help !!

Comment: =DATEDIF([Column1], [Column2],"d")  i have tried this formula..not working !!!!

Answer (score 1):

welcome here. It's very easy, I tried in on SPO, but I believe it will be the same:

**Just do Date2-Date1, output is Number, No decimals:**

[image]

[image]